# Collapsing many categories of variable

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, categorical-data

I have a `df` that includes two categorical variables that have many (>2000) categories. One of the categories of the variable 'installer', makes up a large part of the data:

```
DWE                      35.397980
Government                3.073401
RWE                       2.017508
Commu                     1.814141
DANIDA                    1.757576
                           ...
```

How can I keep let's say the first three categories and collapse the remaining ones in a category called 'other' without having to list them all?

NOTE: I have used replace before for variables with lower cardinality, but had to list all the values I want to replace.

I've tried:

```
unique_values= df['installer'].unique()
for unique in unique_values: 
    if unique != 'DWE' or unique != 'Government' or unique != 'RWE': 
        df['installer'] = df['installer'].replace(unique, 'other')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about first grabbing the three that repeat the most using [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), then filtering and assing the 'Other'

```
categories_to_keep = df['installer'].value_counts().index[:3]

df.loc[
    (~df.installer.isin(categories_to_keep)), 'installer'
] = 'Other'
```